# How to have the selected bottom navigation item raised above the bottom navigation bar?

Tags: flutter

How do I raise the selected bottom navigation bar item? I have tried looking for other packages, but they raise the item above the bar and displace the bottom navigation bar. I want to make it just like in the picture below.

[image: Bottom Navigation Bar with selected item above the other]

Comment: What have you made and coded? What "other packages" did you use?

Comment: I have used the animated_bottom_navigation_bar package, but it doesn't provide the result that I require.

Comment: Please show code of what you have done